# how to add a side pane and annotations anchors to google docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

As a newbye to Google Docs programming I would appreciate some guidance about feasability of following requirement and some pointers into the correct Google Docs/Apps documentation in order to start.

Functionally I would like to implement an annotations pane on the right of my Google Docs documents. 
My goal is to be able to annotate the text with ideas, to-do's, etc. And edit a description associated to those annotations on a right pane, in order to keep the document legible. Obviously such annotations' descriptions must be collapse.

Programatically I have to

- add a pane next to a Google Doc document

  discover when a special "tagging string" is added, e.g. "some text {annotate: Remember-XYZ} more text".

  anchor the annotations in the document

  keep the annotations flowing vis-a-vis their anchor.

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

The capability to add menu and sidebar items to google docs was recently introduced with the DocumentApp. See [Extending Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs) for an introduction.